# Notation: using dot instead of argument

Tags: calculus, notation

Is there any difference between:

1. $f\left(\cdot , \theta \right)$ is continuous in x for each $\theta$
2. $f\left(x , \theta \right)$ is continuous in x for each $\theta$

Comment: The first one doesn't make sense because there is no $x$ in $f(\cdot,\theta)$...

Comment: @RahulNarain, there is x. I changed the initial statement. The point is to understand in what cases should I replace an argument with a dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the first expression is only more nice because $f(\cdot, \theta)$ is a function whereas $f(x,\theta)$ is a value. But it is only estheticism…

But for the first you have only to say that it is continuous.
So the "cleanest" form is $f(\cdot, \theta)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: What do you mean by "$f(x,\theta)$ is a value"? I do not specify x and $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, so it is not a precise value. But for example $x^2$ is not a function it is a number (which changes with $x$). The function is $(x\in \mathbb R \rightarrow x^2 \in\mathbb R)$. And sometimes in order to be less long, you simplify this notation in $\cdot^2$. You can do this when the domain and the image of the function are obvious or not important.

Comment: Now I see. One more question, please: does the notation $f(\cdot, \theta)$ and the fact that f is defined over $X \times \Theta$ make "in x for each θ" part redundant?

Comment: The $x$ is useless because it does not appear more in the expression with the dot. So you say only continuous (for each $\theta\in\Theta$ if you want it to be continuous for all $\theta\in\Theta$)

Comment: I didn't get the comment in parentheses. Did you mean that there is a difference between "_$f(\cdot , \theta)$ is continuous_" and "_$f(\cdot , \theta)$ is continuous for each $\theta$_"?

Comment: Yes, the first means nothing if $\theta$ has not precise value.

Comment: Sounds strange. Suppose $f(x,\theta) = \frac{x}{\theta}$. Obviously, "_f(⋅,θ) is continuous for each θ_" is false (take $\theta = 0$). However, "_f(⋅,θ) is continuous_" is true, isn't it?

Comment: No, the second assertion means nothing if you do not give a value to $\theta$.

Comment: You can say for example $f(\cdot, 1)$ is continuous.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12516/discussion-between-d-l-and-yal-dc)